# Does self.class.delete call a class method?

Tags: ruby

I'm looking at this code in a Ruby library.

Am I correct in assuming that `self.class.delete` calls the **class method** called `delete` on the current object - i.e. the object referenced by `self`.

```
def delete!
  self.class.delete(self.key)
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It calls the class method `delete` for the class of self.

```
class Example
  def self.delete
    puts "Class method. 'self' is a " + self.class.to_s
  end

  def delete!
    puts "Instance method. 'self' is a " + self.class.to_s
    self.class.delete
  end
end

Example.new.delete!
```

Outputs:

```
Instance method. 'self' is a Example
Class method. 'self' is a Class
```

Comment: So self.class.delete is the same as Example.delete. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, disregarding the fact that ruby's 'class methods' are actually class instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a class method. As for whether it's calling it on the current object, it depends on how you're using the terminology. It's calling the method `delete` of the current object's class with the argument `self.key`.